# ng file upload - ng-src not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I expect to show an image from a different source depending on an attribute, so I have the following:

```
<div ng-if="!file.$ngfBlobUrl">
  <img  style="width:50px; height: 50px" ng-src="{{diffent/img/path.jpg}}">
      </div>

<div ngf-if="!!file.$ngfBlobUrl">
  <img style="width:50px; height: 50px" ngf-src="file">
</div>
```

When !file.$ngfBlobUrl === false, that source isn't being used, so that image is not being shown, that's perfect. But I'm getting a 404 error because that img source couldn't be found. How can I prevent that? I mean, the ng-if is put there not to look for that url.

Note: ngf-if and $ngfBlobUrl are from the ng file upload library

Comment: `ngf-if` Is that a typeo?

Comment: is a directive used by ng file upload

Comment: Just use '<img  ngf-src="file || 'diffent/img/path.jpg'">' use `ngf-src` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `ng-src` attribute should reference the Angular model. Ex:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.image = 'http://imgur.com/myimage.jpg'
}

<img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" ng-src="{{image}}">
```

Comment: yes, it does. the thing is that expression references a file that doesn't exist yet, that's why I need to skip that src and show the other one, that shows the selected image to upload (not saved in the server yet)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using two different list, one with the files already uploaded (using ng-src="{{path}}") and another one for the files yet to be uploaded and using the ngf-src directive. I think its a much cleaner and simple way to achieve what I wanted.

Thanks anyway!